# Postgresql Using CTE to delete rows removes all rows

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I have the following table:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
  id SERIAL,
  username varchar(32)
);
INSERT INTO test (username)
VALUES ('Jesse'), ('Jesse'), ('Scott'), ('Scott'), ('John');
```

I want to delete the lowest ID when there is a duplicate row. I made the following query to find the target rows:

```sql
SELECT MIN(id), username
FROM test
GROUP BY username
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

---

When I try to use this in a CTE it ends up deleting every row:

```sql
WITH to_delete AS (
  SELECT MIN(id), username
  FROM test
  GROUP BY username
  HAVING count(*) > 1
)
DELETE FROM test
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM to_delete
);
```

[image: cte]

---

However, when I run the same query and put the CTE as a subquery it works as expected:

```sql
DELETE FROM test
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM test
  GROUP BY username
  HAVING count(*) > 1
);
```

[image: subquery]

I'm sure there is some logic behind this, but I haven't come across the source in my search. Why does the CTE delete every row, but the subquery work as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a column alias to your CTE makes the DELETE work as expected.

```sql
with

  to_delete as (
    select
      min(id) as id,
      username
    from
      test
    group by
      username
    having
      count(*) > 1
  )

delete from
  test
where
  id in (
    select
      id
    from
      to_delete
  )
;
```

```
table test;

 id │ username
════╪══════════
  7 │ Jesse
  9 │ Scott
 10 │ John
(3 rows)
```

The IN operator expects a table with a single column. Your subquery only contains one column, so the name doesn't matter (postgres would assign the column the name of the function, so `min` instead of `id`). Your CTE contains two columns, so you write a subquery that selects one of them, but it wasn't properly aliased as `id`.

```sql
with

  to_delete as (
    select
      min(id) as id,
      username
    from
      test
    group by
      username
    having
      count(*) > 1
  )

select id from to_delete;
```

Results in an error

```
ERROR:  42703: column "id" does not exist
LINE 15: select id from  to_delete;
```

The interesting thing is that instead of erroring out, the DELETE statement treats the WHERE clause as non-existent and continues to delete everything, which is behavior I wouldn't have expected.

Comment: Gah, you're right! I had only done `SELECT *` when testing. I expected an error if I messed something that simple up, I wonder if this is a bug

Comment: This is not a bug, it is expected behavior. It's because it is using a "correlated sub-query", you can find out more here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_doesn.27t_PostgreSQL_report_a_column_not_found_error_when_using_the_wrong_name_in_a_subquery.3F